# Combine two tables and use sort by FIFO

Tags: mysql, sql, fifo

I am stuck with MySQL query.

The 1st table consists of loans for only one loan_number.

```
(loan_number, tranche_number, daydate, bills),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-01', 100),

(555555, 2,'2020-01-06', 100)
```

The 2nd table consists of payments.

```
(loan_number, daydate, bills)

(555555,'2020-01-02', -10),

(555555,'2020-01-03', -10),

(555555,'2020-01-04', -10),

(555555,'2020-01-05', -20),

(555555,'2020-01-07', -50),

(555555,'2020-01-10', -100),

(555555,'2020-01-11', -10)
```

I need to combine two tables above by FIFO order (first comes loan, then number of payments that cover that loan).
Result should look like this.

```
(loan_number, tranche_number, daydate, bills),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-01', 100 ),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-02', -10 ),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-03', -10 ),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-04', -10 ),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-05', -20 ),

(555555, 1,'2020-01-07', -50 ),

(555555, 2,'2020-01-06', 100 ),

(555555, 2,'2020-01-10', -100),

(555555, 2,'2020-01-11', -10)
```

Comment: So do you want to have both loan rows and then all the payments? I assume also that you are wanting this to work against tables that have multiple different loan_numbers

Comment: In fact your example doesn't quite make sense - how do we associate `tranche` with any given payment?

Comment: No, I want a loan and payments that could cover that loan, e.g. first loan 100, payment -50,-50 than second loan and following payments.

Comment: @El Ronnoco, it is the problem that I am trying to solve. I need to match loan and following payments by bill sum. For example, 1st loan has 1st tranche. First sequence of payments that will cover that loan will have also 1st tranche (all payments in that sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `union all`.  However, the trick is to get the `tranch_number`.  Note:  It is possible for a given payment to have more than one tranche.  The following should return the earliest tranche for the payment:

```
select loan_number, tranche_number, daydate, bills
from table1
union all
select t2.loan_number, t1.tranche_number, t2.daydate, t2.bills
from (select t2.*,
             sum(bills) over (partition by loan_number order by daydate) as running_bills
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 join
     (select t1.*,
             sum(bills) over (partition by loan_number order by daydate) as running_bills
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on - (t2.running_bills - t2.bills) >= t1.running_bills - t1.bills and
        - t2.running_bills <= t1.running_bills;
```

Note that this requires MySQL 8+.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d43b26c8d1aaf4e61c5181951cfce8e0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You got it right. This solution works as long as there are no split payments.